# Nor/neither before a different subject?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I came across these sentences on the definifion pages of [**"nor"** (the 3rd def)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nor) and [**"neither"** (the 3rd def)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/neither):

> *Cooking quickly doesn't mean sacrificing flavour. **Nor** does fast food have to be junk food.*

> *He made us no promises. **Neither** did we expect him to.*

Are the following sentences grammatical/fine as well even though *the second clause* of each sentence has *a different subject* from the first one? :

> *Cooking quickly doesn't mean sacrificing flavour **, nor** does fast food have to be junk food.*

> *He made us no promises **and/but neither** did we expect him to.*
>
> *He made us no promises **, neither** did we expect him to.*

*Thank you in advance!*

Comment: Why would you think that clauses need to have the same subject when using "neither" or "nor"? Did you read that somewhere?

Comment: Both the words “neither” and “nor” simply indicate that some new idea is analogously negative to a previous idea. They can certainly be separate clauses. e.g. “He made us no promises. We did not expect him to.” can be made smoother by saying, “He made us no promises, neither did we expect him to.” Note that “neither” serves to take the place of “not.”

Comment: @AnnabethYeung So you think that **"neither"** in the sentence *“He made us no promises, **neither** did we expect him to.”* is grammatical/acceptable, but not not so often used like this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, “nor” is used to introduce another negative idea. “Neither” may be acceptable, but only when it is at the beginning of its own independent clause, and not placed directly after a comma. You may also see the “Formal” note on the 3rd definition of “neither.” That indicates that it isn’t too often used outside of specific, formal occasions. More examples from the Cambridge dictionary:

> To be sure, these are not apps ready for the masses, but **neither** are they supposed to be.
>
> And even amid the recent economic turmoil, **neither** unemployment nor poverty rates have risen above 8 percent here.
>
> No he would not, and **neither** should we.

In general, when looking for clarification on usage when the dictionary definition is unclear, I would recommend looking to other (reputable) dictionaries.

Comment: You said that **"neither"** can be only at the beginning of its own independent clause, and not placed directly after a *comma*. But if you go on [LDOCE, at the 3rd definition of **"neither"**] (https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/neither) , you will see that this is described as a *conjunction* with the sentence example: *The authorities were not sympathetic to the students’ demands, **neither** would they tolerate any disruption.*

Comment: @AlexFrt You need to recognize that “neither” has multiple, **distinct** usages. The one you have used in your comment is highly unusual, as is this entire form; usually, you would use either “nor” or a conjunction in front of “neither.” My answer wasn’t intended to be an end-all, be-all, but more so of a general rule of thumb. If you don’t need to use this structure, don’t use it.